# Crash in x64 version of .net application using p/Invoke

Tags: c#, dll, crash, pinvoke, 64-bit

So, I am trying to run my .NET application in 64 bit mode. I have a dependency on a dll that I can compile for x64 and it loads correctly. I can invoke some calls, but when I try to invoke a specific call, the app just crashes completely. No errors or anything...

The error occurs in one of two places; either here:

```
#include "socket.h"
int SenderAddrSize = sizeof(SOCKADDR_IN);
SOCKADDR_IN CSocket::SenderAddr;

...

char* CSocket::tcpip()
{
if(sockid<0)return NULL;
if(getpeername(sockid, (SOCKADDR *)&SenderAddr, &SenderAddrSize) == SOCKET_ERROR)return NULL;
return inet_ntoa(SenderAddr.sin_addr);
}

...
```

or here:

```
#include "buffer.h"
char CBuffer::retval[20001];
CBuffer::CBuffer()
{
BuffSize = 30;
data = (char*)malloc(BuffSize);
count = 0;
readpos = 0;
writepos = 0;
}

...
```

You can find the full code at my GitHub [HERE](https://github.com/nterry/39DLL/tree/master/src) in [socket.cpp](https://github.com/nterry/39DLL/blob/master/src/socket.cpp) and [buffer.cpp](https://github.com/nterry/39DLL/blob/master/src/buffer.cpp) respectively. **The entry point for the code and the object that calls the above methods are both located in main.cpp**

The p/invoke calls are as follows:

for socket:

```
[DllImport("SockLib", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, EntryPoint = "tcpip")]
public static extern String tcpip(Double socket);
```

and for buffer:

```
 [DllImport("SockLib", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, EntryPoint = "createbuffer")]
 public static extern Double createbuffer();
```

Any ideas why the code is crashing. This works all like a charm in x86, just not in x64...

Also, as a side question... If i write an int to the buffer on a client running in x86 and receive that in on an x64 server (or vice versa), will that int be 4 bytes or 8? does the keyword ***int*** change for platform specific sizes, or do I have to specify ***int64*** to get an 8 byte integer? This applies to the C++ source code part of the larger question above.

Comment: A Double socket?  A Double buffer?  Why is 20001 special?  Don't code alone.  Use System.Net to get ahead.

Comment: I'm not sure... I didn't write this code I'm afraid (I just ported it to Linux and Android)... I have very specific reasons to use this over System.Net and most of it revolves around supporting frameworks that don't have a proper network implementation (or very primitive/restrictive implementations)...

Comment: Never use string as return type . Use IntPtr an get string using http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7b620dhe.aspx. As for int sizes int is Int32 on any .net platform so I suggest using stdint.h and int32_t on c++ side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `string` as a return value in a p/invoke call. That will assume that the memory was allocated using `CoTaskMemAlloc` and so will result in the marshaller calling `CoTaskMemFree` on the returned pointer. That leads to runtime errors.

One option is that you could change the native code to use `CoTaskMemAlloc` for the memory that it allocates to be returned to C#. If you did that then you can just carry on using `string` in your p/invoke return value.

The alternative is to use `malloc` as now, `IntPtr` on the C# side, and export a deallocator from your native code.

To convert from `IntPtr` to string use `Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi()`. Once you've done that you can pass the pointer back to your native DLL so that it can call `free()` on it.

That would look like this:

```
[DllImport("SockLib", CallingConvention=CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern IntPtr tcpip(double socket);
```

And you call it like this:

```
IntPtr strPtr = tcpip(socket);
string str = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(strPtr);
```

And you'll need to do something similar for each of your p/invoke calls that returns a string.

Whether or not you need to deallocate these pointers is not 100% clear. It depends on whether or not you allocated the memory down the C++ code. For example, `tcpip` maps onto a call to `inet_ntoa`. And that returns a pointer to a buffer owned by the sockets library. So your code must not attempt to free it. But if you return memory that was allocated with `malloc` or `new[]`, then you've got to free it also.

---

A few other observations:

- You are returning sockets that are declared as `int` in the C++ code but typing them as  `double` in your C wrappers. Don't do that. Use `int` all the way through.
- The C# type `int` is 32 bytes. For a 64 bit integer use `long`. Unsigned versions are `uint` and `ulong`. For a type that is machine word size, use `IntPtr` or `UIntPtr`.

Comment: Ok, so I understood about half of that... Could you explain it in a little bit more newbish manner... What classes and where do I wrap? I do use C naming conventions to avoid the C++ mangling issues. I also use Cdecl (if that matters). Could you give me an example using my code with a little more context around it?

Comment: Your C++ code is a bunch of classes. You can't call methods of classes that with p/invoke.

Comment: So whats the fix? I have a main.cpp that calls into the classes... I guess im just confused as to what ther is other than classes...

Comment: Ah, you've already wrapped. Why didn't you show that code in the question?!

Comment: That wrapper looks reasonable to me. The main issue that I can see then is how you return strings.

Comment: I added a reference to my github.... I guess I assumed you looked at my code... Could you give it the once-over and maybe see why p/invoke crashes when calling my dll in 64 bit mode?

Comment: I've updated the answer. The biggest problem I can see is the incorrect `string` return value in your p/invoke. That's wrong always. Your 32 bit code is no good either. You are just getting lucky.

Comment: Ok, so my main issue is that I cant just pass back a string without some form of C# massaging? Can you give me a small example of both solutions? Like, what do you mean by a deallocator?

Comment: You probably don't need a deallocator. I've added some more to the answer. I honestly think I've done the best I can. You should have enough to move on now. Try to cut down the problem. Try the smallest program you can come up with that tests this lib. And then broaden it out. Don't run your entire program all at once! Take small steps to learn and gain confidence.